# Improperly set display when running a root crontab job involving GUI

Tags: display, root, cron

When running the script below from my local user crontab, with `sudo`  before `/usr/bin/FreeFileSync` (last script's line), a small progress window opens on my GUI and things go well. The only thing is I have to input my sudo passwd, which makes it interactive and somewhat unwieldly.

Root privileges are necessary to run FFS, otherwise it complains about not having rights to get to some directories and files being backed up.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# define default display and pass it on to any child process
# from within the running shell
DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY

/usr/bin/FreeFileSync /home/user/bu-1.ffs_batch 2> \ 
   /home/user/bu-1.ffs_log
```

When I call the same script from my root crontab with `sudo crontab -e`, `FreeFileSync` never gets to run because of the following error:

```
$ cat /home/user/bu-1.ffs_log
16:35:01: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

As can be seen, I have`export DISPLAY=:0.0` within the script and my root crontab file is equipped with:

```
$ sudo crontab -e | head -4
[sudo] password for user:

1 SHELL=/bin/bash
2 PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
3 HOME=/
4 MAILTO=root
```

Can someone help troubleshooting the error ?

**EDIT:** Could it be that running this from root's crontab fails because user `root` as no open session and therefore no stdout to which to display?
*Can I circumvent that difficulty by asking root to display to a current user's session's stdout?* It seems to be worth a shot if doable; if so how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could **configure `sudo` to not need a password for a particular
command** and go back to using a non-root cron. 
For this, assuming a user id of "user" wants to run the command `FreeFileSync` as root, create a file `/etc/sudoers.d/user` with

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/FreeFileSync
```

The command must be given with a full pathname. If you don't explicitly list the args to the command, then any args will be allowed by sudo.
Replace `ALL` by your hostname (not localhost) to be more secure.

This assumes file `/etc/sudoers` has the line: (note # is **not** a comment)

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

If not, then just add the user entry to /etc/sudoers. Be careful editing this file: use visudo, or ensure you have root logged in or a shell running root to be able to do any repairs.

Your user crontab entry can then just have the command:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 sudo /usr/bin/FreeFileSync /home/user/bu-1.ffs_batch 2>/home/user/bu-1.ffs_log
```

ubuntu sudo will preserve some environment variables for the command including DISPLAY and HOME (see output of `sudo sudo -V`) so the program will be able to read the ~/.Xauthority file (continue reading for details).

---

Alternatively, **to keep using a root crontab:**
if when you do `ps alxww|grep X` you find your X11 server running with an `-auth` option, something like this:

```
/usr/bin/X :0 ... -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 ...
```

it means clients must connect using the secret in the file `/var/run/lightdm/root/:0`. This file holds a copy of the secret in the user's `~/.Xauthority` file.
This "secret" is just an arbitrary random number.
If you are root you can read both files, so your client can simply provide in the environment:

```
XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0
```

Alternatively, you can set the HOME to that of the user of the display,
`HOME=/home/user` so that the right `.Xauthority` file is found there.

Alternatively, you can export the secret from this to root's home:

```
xauth -f /home/user/.Xauthority nextract - localhost/unix:0 | sudo xauth -f /root/.Xauthority nmerge -
```

and then XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority or just HOME=/root.

Comment: Thanks much @meuh ! I will try this now...  Is it important to place `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`at the beginning of the `/etc/sudoers` file or can I put it anywhere in that file ?

Comment: Usually it is the last line. You would need to create the directory, make sure it is rwx to root only. Check your sudoers man page first.

Comment: @Cbhihe I added some info on xauth.

Comment: Trying to digest sudoers(5) right now. On `ps alxww | grep X`, you probably want to write `sudo ps alxw | [...]` lest followers may be confused with a `personality` problem. Also do you mean to repeat the w (wide output) option in `ps`for some reason ?

Comment: Should I assume your line `user ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/FreeFileSync`  was sanitized for the sake of generality and I should in fact create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` not called "user" but some existing  user name ? Should I likewise assume that tht same line should in fact read: `real-username  real-hostname = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/FreeFileSync` One example in sudoers(5) manpage suggests so. Tx.

Comment: @Cbhihe yes, *user* should be the real user name, and ALL can be a real hostname if you want proper security. And the filename /etc/sudoers.d/user is usually the real user name, so it is easier to add a file per user.

Comment: @Cbhihe  I didnt need a `sudo ps`, but I'm not actually on ubuntu at the moment, and the `ww` is just habit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26705/discussion-between-cbhihe-and-meuh).